# Can I use an Xbox Guitar Hero 2 controller for Retro/Grade on PC?

Tags: hardware, guitar-hero

I just bought [Retro/Grade](http://store.steampowered.com/app/222660) and my computer doesn't automatically detect my Xbox 360 GH2 X-plorer, instead fails to automatically find a driver for it, leaving me unable to choose the Guitar control option in Retro/Grade.

What do I do?

Comment: Wasn't able to create a `retro-grade` tag, nor could I find a peripherals one. Feel free to retag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as complicated as it might seem, all you need to do is to tell your computer to treat it as a traditional Xbox 360 Wired controller.

If you're on Windows 7, all you need to do is to go to `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers` in the Windows Explorer (<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, if you're the lazy type), right click on the Guitar Hero X-plorer icon and instead of automatically finding a driver, choose find a manual driver, and under the "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer" choose the Microsoft controller category, and choose one of the exisiting Xbox 360 Controller drivers.